# Richtext in Django App

Tags: django, richtext, django-tinymce

I would like to add some very basic rich text editing in my charfields, only bold, italic and a custom fontsize selector (small-normal-large  -- relative to another model field setting).  At first I tried to use django-tinymce, but when using a formset I had some problems that the media files for tinymce only applied to the first form in the set, and my added js function doesnt work.  Maybe I need a custom widget for this small-normal-large fontsize selector anyway (or do this as a model field).

Is it recommendable to user TinyMCE and try to customize it in this case (if so, how), or is there a more straightforward way to go using the form I've already created?

Here's what I have in my form (dynamically changing the textarea size, and calling js function in the template to limit chars):

```
text=forms.CharField(max_length = 1000, widget=forms.widgets.Textarea()) 
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     size = kwargs.pop('size')
     maxChars = kwargs.pop('maxChars')
     super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     self.fields['text'].widget.attrs['onkeypress'] = 'return textCounter(this, this.form.counter, %d);' % maxChars
     self.fields['text'].widget.attrs['rows'] = size
     self.fields['text'].widget.attrs['cols'] = '40'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ckeditor, which you can enable without any django-app. An other alternative is the (very) basic glow editor, see BBC's glow homepage.

Personnally I would not include that javascript in your form btw, but include it in the template.

Comment: Ok, went with ckeditor, this seems to be doing the trick, nice one.  Suppose in this case since I will be defining the textareas in the template as opposed to thru the form widget, I will take your advice on moving the javascript all into the template.  Im a novice, so still getting used to how to play with the template tags.  Thanks for the advice!

Comment: For more information about forms and their media, this might be of use to you: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/media/